# Switch to windows containers with docker for windows toolbox

Tags: docker, windows-7, switch-statement, toolbox

I have installed docker for windows toolbox on windows 7 64 bit os. I am unable to switch to windows container using docker menu as the docker icon is not available in systray. Docker service is also not available. Docker CLI executable isn't available on any folder. However docker commands are working and simple containers are getting created.

Any suggestions for how to switch to windows containers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on icon at bottom-right corner of Windows task bar

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All
```

Answer (score 3):

Docker toolbox includes docker machine to run docker inside of a Linux VM. There is no option to run native Windows containers with this install.

To run native Windows containers, you need a HyperV based install on Windows 10 or Server 2016: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/