# How to switch to windows container on window 10 home docker desktop as options is disabled in my case

Tags: docker, containers

I have the [`Switch to windows container`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5d19.png) option disabled.
And when I build a new image the following error is shown:
[image: Screenshot of error]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed a HyperV?

As suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51757876/9330208) to run native Windows containers you need a HyperV based install on [Windows 10](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/).